# How could a customization on Windows affects Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

I am using dual boot on my laptop(Lenovo Legion s7) Ubuntu and Windows 10. In am using ICUE software in Windows to customize my keyboards lightning. The keyboard does not need a software for lightning but if you do not use a software you must use one of six lighting modes you can only change brightness. To change the color of lightning modes you need a software like ICUE.

However yesterday I changed the color of static lightning mode(the one that every key has same color) from white to red with ICUE on Windows 10 and somehow when I got back to Ubuntu I noticed the color of static lightning turned into red. How could a customization on Windows affects Ubuntu with a built-in keyboard?

Comment: By writing to the firmware of the keyboard.

Comment: Probably the ICUE software you mention is needed only to **change** parameters that are stored permanently in keyboard controller's memory, and once these parameters are changed, the keyboard just uses them, completely independent of the OS you are currently using on the computer.

Comment: @Sebastian Does it mean ICUE wrote to the firmware of keyboard?

Comment: @raj Normally when I changed from win to ubuntu changes that I made with ICUE does not apply to ubuntu. But this time it applied. What I was wondering is what changed this time because usually this does not happens.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything more without knowing how internally the ICUE software operates. I'm only hypothesizing. Some changes might be temporary (controlled by ICUE software itself, and last as long as ICUE is running) while others are persistent (written to keyboard controller's memory and don't need ICUE running). It may also be that there are different modes of applying changes in the software. It is also possible that when you shut down Windows, ICUE reverts the changes that you have made, and for some reason this time it didn't.